# Unix / Sed strip x number of digits from a string

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, tr

Have spent quite a while trying to figure out how to strip a certain number of digits from a string. In this case I want to strip off the date portion only (noted below in YYYYMMDD format - in the 8 digits that follow the 'D'.

I thought about taking 8 characters following the D, but thought maybe it'd be safer to find the instance we have 8 consecutive digits, in case the filename changes in the future.

**Example string:**   HelloWorld.D20150101T121501.xml

**Expected result:**  20150101

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "HelloWorld.D20150101T121501.xml" | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{8}).*/\1/'
20150101
```